# copy local profile to new (same OS) computer

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I have my main laptop which I have set up just the way I like it on Windows 7 (i.e. disabled areo, show all icons in notification area and customized the start menu to name a few). I've recently got a second laptop (also Win 7) that I'd like to copy my settings to and I've made so many little tweaks it would be really hard to re-create the settings "by hand" and was wondering if there was a way to copy the settings across.

Both laptops are Win 7 Ultimate with local profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want Windows Easy Transfer. (Search in the start menu, it's built into Windows 7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (posted by me elsewhere on superuser.com)...

https://superuser.com/a/769138/333580

Good for renaming any user by copying the profile and creating a new Default user with those settings. You can then easily create new user(s) with your preferred settings.