# Root user file Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I bought a used Windows computer which was reset to stock with the default Administrator user named "John Doe".  I have changed my "username" to what I want but the user's account folder still retains the name "John Doe".  I've researched this and found a number of registry changes (which I'm not comfortable doing).  I've read I can create another user, move all the contents to the new one, and delete the old account...but then will my applications continue looking for the old account's folder?

Please help.  I'm simply trying to change the name of the root user folder to my name in lieu of "John Doe".

Thanks!

Comment: Alright buddy, let me clarify a couple of things: First, that computer was not reset to *stock*, if it has a user named John Doe.  Second, there is not *root* user in Windows. Rather it is called *administrator* user.Just in case you didn't know these.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (particularly since it is a new computer) is to make a new 'Administrator' account from the John Doe account and then delete the John Doe account from your new user account. To create a administrator user account in Windows 8.1 i believe the following will work:

1. Right click the Start icon
2. Click 'Control Panel'
3. Click 'Add or remove user accounts'
4. Click 'Create new account'
5. Type a name for the account and ensure you change the radio button choice from "Standard user" to "Administrator"
6. Click 'Create Account'

Once that is done, log out and then log back into the newly created account. Follow steps one to four again and then select the account to be removed and choose 'Delete Account'

Please correct me if any of this is wrong, I am not at my Windows 8.1 machine at the moment to confirm.

The alternative is to create the new account but then follow the instructions in the answer to [Rename profile folder on Windows 7/8](https://superuser.com/questions/570601/rename-profile-folder-on-windows-7-8)

Also when you create new user account, your applications will continue to work, but their settings *may be* lost.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes!

Comment: You do not have to delete the old account right away. If there are any settings for applications you want to check or move over you can leave the old account until you are happy you are not going to loose anything then delete it.