# Can't change user folder Name om Windows 7 because it says that the folder is opened in another program

Tags: windows-7

I've been following a guide here on how to change the Name and path of user folder ([Rename profile folder on Windows 7/8](https://superuser.com/questions/570601/rename-profile-folder-on-windows-7-8) ) , but when i get to changing the Name in file Explorer it says that the folder is opened in another program. I don't know how this is possible becouse i shut Down the pc before reloging and there is no proces in task manager form the other user.

(sorry for creating another thread but this 50 reputation system makes it so i cant just reply with this question to the originaly guide and forces me to create this)

Comment: this is exactly what you should do if you have a new question *about* an old question: ask it as a new question, with a link to the question you're referencing. This is actually best asked in a question and not in a comment, because now new people will see and be able to answer.

Comment: At which step in the process do you get this error?

Comment: At step #2, just trying to rename in file explorer. Says it's open in another program but i don't understand how that is possible.

Comment: to confirm: you're on an admin account as well? Can you reboot and try again? Do you have any program installed that runs as admin or something like that?

Comment: I am an admin on both and tried rebooting like 3 times now. I reboot and just open file explorer on the second user. The second user was created for this guide and i have just always been using the first user for everything so everything i have ever run was on there, but no process shows up as specificly run by the first user in task manager, just as SYSTEM.

Comment: My guess would be that there are automated startup programs running under that user, like OneDrive or whatever.

Comment: Ok, that's a good guess, thank you. But how do i check what those automated startup programs are and how to close them, any help?

Comment: @Smok7kp - Autoruns. The better solution to this problem is not following bad advice.  There are free third-party programs that will take files from one profile and move it to another profile (or you can do it by hand).  Yes; THe answer your are following is providing bad advice and it obviously doesn't work

Comment: Specific to your question (and not a good idea), you can use the system internals process explorer to look for open handles under that path and close them.  I highly suggest that you follow @Ramhound advice instead.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for your answer, i don't think the guide i have been following is 100% wrong, but your solution is simpler. I had to do this for a project so i allready just figured it out by running what i had to run on that other user, so i guess i can just switch users whenever, or maybe i will try moveing the files, i'm scared of loseing stuff tho. When i tried moveing them by hand not everything wanted to move but the 3rd party programs maybe will help with that.